# How to reverse pyvis network graph to another direction

Tags: python, html, graph, networkx, pyvis

I have a pyvis network amazing graph and I want to change arrows from one side to another, that all leads to red point.

[image: 1]

Is there any function of it?

Is there any other way to reverse the arrow?

adding my whole messy code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyarrow.feather as feather
from pyvis import network as net
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
import networkx  as nx
from graph_based_clustering import ConnectedComponentsClustering
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import markov_clustering as mc
from node2vec import Node2Vec

df = pd.read_feather('block_100000')


value= df[["input_prev_tx_hash","input_prev_value"]]
value = value.drop_duplicates()
value = value.dropna()

def get_size(node):
    value_list = list()
    for i in node:
        v = value[value["input_prev_tx_hash"]== i]["input_prev_value"].item()
        v = v/1000000000
        value_list.append(v)
    return value_list



#edges
edges = df[["hash", "input_prev_tx_hash"]].copy()
edges = edges.dropna()
edges = edges.drop_duplicates()
edges.drop(edges[edges["hash"]=="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"].index, inplace = True)
edges.drop(edges[edges["input_prev_tx_hash"]=="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"].index, inplace = True)

print(edges)
features = df[["hash"]].copy()
features = features.drop_duplicates()
features.drop(features[features["hash"]=="0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"].index, inplace = True)

#features.sort_values(by=["1"])

nodes_1 = features["hash"].to_numpy()
nodes_1 = nodes_1[4].split()

edges_1 = edges[edges['hash'].isin(nodes_1)]

nodes_2 = edges_1['input_prev_tx_hash'].to_numpy()
edges_2 = edges[edges['hash'].isin(edges_1['input_prev_tx_hash'])]
nodes_3 = edges_2['input_prev_tx_hash'].to_numpy()
edges_3 = edges[edges['hash'].isin(edges_2['input_prev_tx_hash'])]
nodes_4 = edges_3['input_prev_tx_hash'].to_numpy()
edges_4 = edges[edges['hash'].isin(edges_3['input_prev_tx_hash'])]
nodes_5 = edges_4['input_prev_tx_hash'].to_numpy()
edges_5 = edges[edges['hash'].isin(edges_4['input_prev_tx_hash'])]
nodes_6 = edges_5['input_prev_tx_hash'].to_numpy()
edges_6 = edges[edges['hash'].isin(edges_5['input_prev_tx_hash'])]
nodes_7 = edges_6['input_prev_tx_hash'].to_numpy()
edges_7 = edges[edges['hash'].isin(edges_6['input_prev_tx_hash'])]
nodes_8 = edges_7['input_prev_tx_hash'].to_numpy()
edges_8 = edges[edges['hash'].isin(edges_7['input_prev_tx_hash'])]
nodes_9 = edges_8['input_prev_tx_hash'].to_numpy()
edges_9 = edges[edges['hash'].isin(edges_8['input_prev_tx_hash'])]
nodes_10 = edges_9['input_prev_tx_hash'].to_numpy()
edges_10 = edges[edges['hash'].isin(edges_9['input_prev_tx_hash'])]
nodes_11 = edges_10['input_prev_tx_hash'].to_numpy()
edges_11 = edges[edges['hash'].isin(edges_10['input_prev_tx_hash'])]
nodes_12 = edges_11['input_prev_tx_hash'].to_numpy()
edges_12 = edges[edges['hash'].isin(edges_11['input_prev_tx_hash'])]
nodes_13 = edges_12['input_prev_tx_hash'].to_numpy()
edges_13 = edges[edges['hash'].isin(edges_12['input_prev_tx_hash'])]
nodes_14 = edges_13['input_prev_tx_hash'].to_numpy()
edges_14 = edges[edges['hash'].isin(edges_13['input_prev_tx_hash'])]
#nodes_1 = nodes_1.tolist()
nodes_2 = nodes_2.tolist()
nodes_3 = nodes_3.tolist()
nodes_4 = nodes_4.tolist()
nodes_5 = nodes_5.tolist()
nodes_6 = nodes_6.tolist()
nodes_7 = nodes_7.tolist()
nodes_8 = nodes_8.tolist()
nodes_9 = nodes_9.tolist()
nodes_10 = nodes_10.tolist()
nodes_11 = nodes_11.tolist()
nodes_12 = nodes_12.tolist()
nodes_13 = nodes_13.tolist()
nodes_14 = nodes_14.tolist()

edges_1 = edges_1.to_records(index=False).tolist()
edges_2 = edges_2.to_records(index=False).tolist()
edges_3 = edges_3.to_records(index=False).tolist()
edges_4 = edges_4.to_records(index=False).tolist()
edges_5 = edges_5.to_records(index=False).tolist()
edges_6 = edges_6.to_records(index=False).tolist()
edges_7 = edges_7.to_records(index=False).tolist()
edges_8 = edges_8.to_records(index=False).tolist()
edges_9 = edges_9.to_records(index=False).tolist()
edges_10 = edges_10.to_records(index=False).tolist()
edges_11 = edges_11.to_records(index=False).tolist()
edges_12 = edges_12.to_records(index=False).tolist()
edges_13 = edges_13.to_records(index=False).tolist()
edges_14 = edges_14.to_records(index=False).tolist()




g=net.Network(bgcolor='#222222', font_color='white', directed=True)
# use 'directed=True' for arrows showing the direction of the edges
g.add_nodes(nodes_1, color=['red'])
g.add_nodes(nodes_2, size=get_size(nodes_2))
g.add_nodes(nodes_3, size=get_size(nodes_3))
g.add_nodes(nodes_4, size=get_size(nodes_4))
g.add_nodes(nodes_5, size=get_size(nodes_5))
g.add_nodes(nodes_6, size=get_size(nodes_6))
g.add_nodes(nodes_7, size=get_size(nodes_7))
g.add_nodes(nodes_8, size=get_size(nodes_8))
g.add_nodes(nodes_9, size=get_size(nodes_9))
g.add_nodes(nodes_10, size=get_size(nodes_10))
g.add_nodes(nodes_11, size=get_size(nodes_11))
g.add_nodes(nodes_12, size=get_size(nodes_12))
g.add_nodes(nodes_13, size=get_size(nodes_13))
g.add_nodes(nodes_14, size=get_size(nodes_14))


g.add_edges(edges_1)
g.add_edges(edges_2)
g.add_edges(edges_3)
g.add_edges(edges_4)
g.add_edges(edges_5)
g.add_edges(edges_6)
g.add_edges(edges_7)
g.add_edges(edges_8)
g.add_edges(edges_9)
g.add_edges(edges_10)
g.add_edges(edges_11)
g.add_edges(edges_12)
g.add_edges(edges_13)
g.add_edges(edges_14)

g.show("example.html")
```

here is how edges looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv24x.png)

The idea is that it I pass the hash from which it starts to create edges, from is in hash column and to is in input_prev_tx_hash

I tried with networkx graph, but then visualization is not the same, I cannot make the same nice visualization with html like here in networkx graph.

Comment: What is `edges`? In general, an edge is a tuple `(from, to)`. You could simply reverse it. In your code you have a variable called `edges`, which seems to contain that information. However you do not show it.

Comment: Sorry, my code is such a mess. here is edges:

#edges
edges = df[["hash", "input_prev_tx_hash"]].copy()
edges = edges.dropna()
edges = edges.drop_duplicates()



features = df[["hash"]].copy()
features = features.drop_duplicates()


so will try to reverse edges

Comment: Ok, have no idea how to reverse it...

Comment: That does not really help. 
How does edges look like? Could you print it? And please add that and the code to the question and not in the comments.

Comment: updated the main description now

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you should be able to reverse the edges by adding `[::-1]` to the lines `edges_n = ...`. E.g. `edges_1 = edges_1.to_records(index=False).tolist()[::-1].`

Comment: I tried you rsuggestion but the arrows remained the same.

Comment: I used this one edges_1 = [(edg[1], edg[0]) for edg in edges_1]
and it swap places in array list. thanks a lot for idea!